# Destruir array em C++

Tags: array, c++, destrutor

Fala devs, eu estou tentando destruir o array Roda mas recebo uma mensagem de erro:

> error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

Como eu posso corrigir o erro? Segue os meus arquivos se puderem dar uma olhada:

pratica01.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include "veiculo.h"
#include "veiculo.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    cout << "Primeira aplicação C++" << endl;

    /*
    Veiculo veiculo1("v1");
    {
        Veiculo veiculo2("v2");
        {
            Veiculo veiculo3("v3");
        }
    }*/

    Veiculo *obj1 = new Veiculo("v1");
    {
        Veiculo *obj2 = new Veiculo("v2");
        {
            Veiculo *obj3 = new Veiculo("v3");

            obj3->setNumRodas(3, 3);
            cout << "Número de rodas: " << obj3->getNumRodas() << endl;

            obj3->~Veiculo();
        }
        obj2->setNumRodas(2, 2);
        cout << "Número de rodas: " << obj2->getNumRodas() << endl;

        obj2->~Veiculo();
    }
    obj1->setNumRodas(1, 1);
    cout << "Número de rodas: " << obj1->getNumRodas() << endl;

    obj1->~Veiculo();

    return 0;
}
```

veiculo.h

```
#ifndef VEICULO_H_INCLUDED
#define VEICULO_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;

class Roda
{
    Roda()
    {

        cout << "Objeto construído!" << endl;
    }

    ~Roda()
    {
        cout << "Objeto destruído!" << endl;
    }
};

class Veiculo
{
private:
    string nome;
    int num_rodas;
    Roda *rodas;

public:
    Veiculo(const char *param);

    ~Veiculo();

    void setNumRodas(int nRodas, int tamanho);

    int getNumRodas();

};

#endif // VEICULO_H_INCLUDED
```

veiculo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Veiculo::Veiculo(const char *param)
{
    this->nome = string(param);
    this->rodas = NULL;
    cout << "Um objeto foi construído com nome " << nome << endl;
}

Veiculo::~Veiculo()
{
    cout << "O objeto " << nome << " foi destruído!" << endl;
    delete [] Roda;
};

void Veiculo::setNumRodas(int nRodas, int tamanho)
{
    this->num_rodas = nRodas;
    Roda *rodas[tamanho];

}

int Veiculo::getNumRodas()
{
    return this->num_rodas;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Abordando o problema mencionado na pergunta:

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa excluir a propriedade `rodas` que é um array/ponteiro. O problema está no fato de estar tentando remover o tipo `Roda` e não a propriedade `rodas` da sua classe `Veiculo`:

```
cout << "O objeto " << nome << " foi destruído!" << endl;
delete [] Roda; // "Roda" é um tipo
```

O correto para a exclusão seria:

```
cout << "O objeto " << nome << " foi destruído!" << endl;
delete[] this->rodas; // Agora "rodas" é uma propriedade
```

---

#### E para que consiga compilar o código ao acessar a propriedade corretamente:

É necessário que inclua o arquivo `veiculo.h` no começo do arquivo `veiculo.cpp`, dado que o mesmo não se encontra no código que colocou na pergunta. O arquivo precisa saber que o tipo `Roda` possui declarações em outro arquivo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "veiculo.h"
using namespace std;
```

Altere os acessos dos métodos da classe `Roda` para `public`, dado que por padrão [o C++ os configura como private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes). Caso contrário, as declarações não serão encontradas em outros arquivos:

```
public: // Alterando nível de acesso
    Roda()
    {
        cout << "Objeto construído!" << endl;
    }

    ~Roda()
    {
        cout << "Objeto destruído!" << endl;
    }
```

E para compilar, basta remover o `#include veiculo.cpp` do arquivo `pratica01.cpp` e compilar os arquivos `pratica01.cpp` e `veiculo.cpp` juntos; é importante que os arquivos `veiculo.cpp` e `pratica01.cpp` conheçam o arquivo `veiculo.h` e sejam indicados juntos na compilação:

```
g++ pratica01.cpp veiculo.cpp -o program
```

Mas eles não precisam saber da existência um do outro. Caso contrário, o arquivo `pratica01.cpp`, que antes possuía as duas inclusões, veria que existem declarações duplicadas para os tipos e uma mensagem como abaixo seria retornada durante o processo de compilação:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::Veiculo(char const*)':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Veiculo::Veiculo(char const*)'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::Veiculo(char const*)':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Veiculo::Veiculo(char const*)'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::~Veiculo()':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x114): multiple definition of `Veiculo::~Veiculo()'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x114): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::~Veiculo()':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x114): multiple definition of `Veiculo::~Veiculo()'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x114): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::setNumRodas(int, int)':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): multiple definition of `Veiculo::setNumRodas(int, int)'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjaUKpo.o: in function `Veiculo::getNumRodas()':
veiculo.cpp:(.text+0x2fc): multiple definition of `Veiculo::getNumRodas()'; /tmp/ccuappVo.o:pratica01.cpp:(.text+0x2fc): first defined here
```